# Trigger SQL Agent job based on text in error log for an AG failover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, ssrs, failover, alerts

I have a 2 node AG setup (Not an FCI). I need to configure an alert to trigger a job based on a string found in the error log showing that the node is now the new primary.
The string I want to use is:

> 'primary_pending' to 'primary_normal'

This is what shows in the error log when the secondary node becomes primary. I want the alert to kick off a SQL job I created to automate our SSRS to use the new primary replica.

Below is the alert I setup, but it is not triggering properly. I do have the alert configured to execute the job when this alert is triggered.

When a failover happens, the job does not kick off. I'm guessing it may be due to the error number used. I found a blog post about using this, but can't seem to find it again. The error log does not display any error number in the line with this text, so I think that is the issue.

How can I get an alert to trigger based on text it finds in the error log, or is there a better way to do this?

I do have conditional logic to check for primary / secondary status in all my jobs, but I can't use that for this job as I want it to only execute 1x (when it first becomes primary).

[image: Failover alert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `<all databases>` in the database name selection.  The error you are checking for is not related to a specific database, so having a database specified is effectively filtering it so the alert doesn't care about it.

I just tested this using RAISERROR to log a message that included "'this' or 'that'" and it worked fine.  At first I thought you may need to delimit the single quotes, but in my test I didn't and it worked.